# Convert Week of the Year to Date in PySpark

Tags: date, datetime, pyspark, week-number

I have a PySpark dataframe with 'Week_of_the_year' column. '202005' means 5th week of year 2020.
How can I convert it to 'date' format, maybe convert to mid-date (Wednesday) of that week?

Example: I want '202005' to show as '2020-01-29'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **`to_date`** function on your date with **`3(day of week: Wednesday)`** *concatenated*, like **`2020053`**, where 2020 is year, 05 is week of year, 3 is week day number. Refer to [Java Simple Date format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for info on date time chars.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("new_date", F.to_date(F.concat("old_date",F.lit("3")), "yyyywwu")).show()

#+--------+----------+
#|old_date|  new_date|
#+--------+----------+
#|  202005|2020-01-29|
#+--------+----------+
```